# How to differentiate side and wheel buttons with cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, events

I have mouse with 5 buttons. They are left, right, wheel and 2 side buttons (back/forward). Is there any way to check, whether side button ("back" for example) was pressed? I learning cocoa's documentation about mouse event. At the moment I know that there is `- (void)otherMouseDown:(NSEvent *)event;` method, which is called whenever other (not right/left) button was pressed. But documentation tells nothing about additional information about which button was actually pressed. How to overcome this?

Comment: Have you tried the `buttonNumber` property of `NSEvent`?

Comment: Also in some cases back/forward buttons will not trigger this event. Like with my Logitech MX Master 3: it depends on a vendor. Only wheel press triggers `otherMouseDown` in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-(void)scrollWheel:(NSEvent *)event;` [method of NSResponder and so also from NSViews](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsresponder/1534192-scrollwheel?language=objc)

`- (void)rightMouseDown:(NSEvent *)event;` [same way](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsresponder/1524727-rightmousedown?language=objc)

`- (void)otherMouseDown:(NSEvent *)event` as you know

but also..

```objectivec
-(void)someAction:(id)sender 
{
    NSEvent *event = [NSApp currentEvent];
    if (event.type == NSEventTypeLeftMouseUp ||
        event.type == NSEventTypeLeftMouseDown) 
    { 
        if (event.clickCount == 2) {  
            // doubleClick
        }
    } 
    else if (event.type == NSEventTypeOtherMouseDown) 
    {
        if (event.buttonNumber==4) 
        {
            //i think first button is 0, so 5 should be 4.
        }
    }
}
```

AppKit's NSEvent.h has everything you need just check the `type` of the event first and then go for `buttonNumber` and what ever you choose